# На чем сделан интерфейс в программе Kaspersky antivirus?

Tags: c++, интерфейс, kaspersky

Хочу вас спросить, я недавно увидел на википедии, что Kaspersky написан на c++, скажите пожалуйста, как они создали интерфейс? WinApi, Qt, или что-то другое?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Графический интерфейс последнего KIS (2019) написан с использованием .NET и WPF. Ядро, наиболее вероятно, написано на C++. Не знаю почему, но я считал, что интерфейс написан на Qt. Вероятно, раньше так оно и было.